# Kafka lost messages

Tags: apache-kafka

Here my scenario:

configure kafka with retention time = 6h
create topic
send messages in 16 topics
run a consumer on topics 0-7
=> messages are received
wait about one hour
start a second consumer on topics 8-15
=> no messages consumed after few minutes, poll returns 0 messages after a one minute timeout
send messages on 16 topics
=> both consumers receive messages

We have noticed several times that behaviour when we send messages on a topic without consumer and start consumer later. Messages sent in the broker before the consumer connect are lost.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed to specify the consumer configuration parameter `auto.offset.reset`. Default value is `latest` (or `largest` for pre v0.9) but it seems you want to set it to `earliest` (or `smallest` for pre v0.9).

You add is to you `KafkaConsumer` configuration properties.

See http://kafka.apache.org/0100/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs